# Inject retrofit using dagger using `base_url` from firebase remote config

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit, dagger, firebase-remote-config

I know that we can inject retrofit using dagger in the following manner when the `BASE_URL` is fixed:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();

    return retrofit;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
ApiCallInterface provideApiCallInterface(Retrofit retrofit) {
    return retrofit.create(ApiCallInterface.class);
}
```

But, the problem here is my `BASE_URL` comes from firebase remote config, and I can obtain that only after runtime which is too late as dagger will initialize retrofit before that. How can this problem be solved? All the tutorials and examples that I see, work with static base urls and hence dont encounter this problem.

I am using `remoteconfig` for my base url so that I can control the app environment without pushing in app updates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer: how are you using firebase remote config to give BASE_URL? is there any documentation you have referred?

Comment: Same question here. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Retrofit docs](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/)

1. About base_URL:

> Endpoint values may be a full URL.
>
> Values which have a host replace the host of baseUrl and values also
> with a scheme replace the scheme of baseUrl.
> Examples:
>
> Base URL: http://example.com/
>
> Endpoint: https://github.com/square/retrofit/
>
> Result: https://github.com/square/retrofit/

**So if endpoint's URL holds full URL, base URL will be replaced|ignored**

2. About GET-annotation (the same with POST):

> A relative or absolute path, or full URL of the endpoint. This value
> is optional if the first parameter of the method is annotated with
> @Url.

**So with @URL parameter of your endpoint and empty GET parameter you can set full URL in runtime with parameter @URL of your endpoint**

So try with something like this in your endpoint:

```
@GET()
fun getData(@Url url : String): Call<SomeResult>
```

and set parameter of method (full URL) in runtime

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by leaving the Firebase Remote Config version to 17.0.0 and using the FirebaseRemoteConfig#setDefaults function.

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:17.0.0'
```

Class. Note the setConfigSettingsAsync is still async, setDefaults stays sync.

```
private final FirebaseRemoteConfig mFirebaseRemoteConfig;
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder...);
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(R.xml.remote_config_defaults);
mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate().addOnCompleteListener(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943218/9599716) above by sergiy tikhonov you can also use an [interceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/) to intercept your requests and swap the `host` with your firebase remote config's BASE_URL.

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/8571a8207a5815cca1fb) for an example.